# extjs grid Select All checkbox issue

Tags: asp.net, extjs

I Want to get the total count of rows fetched when the user selects/checks SelectAll checkbox in Extjs grid.

Pls let me know how to do this.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

To get all the rows in a grid, use:

`store.getRange();`

To only get the selected rows use:

```
var selectionModel = grid.getSelectionModel();
var selected = selectionModel.getSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like,

```
var sm = grid.getSelectionModel();
var Selected_record_count = sm.getCount()
```

Explanation;

`getSelectionModel()` - Returns the selection model being used and creates it via the configuration if it has not been created already.

`getCount()` - Returns the count of selected records.